# Unable to create Vue app, got Error: you are using an outdated version of NPM, But I have the latest version

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-cli, nvm

My environment:

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04.3` `Node Version: v18.18.2` `NPM Version: 10.2.1` `Vue version: @vue/cli 5.0.8`

I used NVM to install Node.
Then I proceeded to check the version of npm, which was `9.x`, So I updated it to `10.2.1`
Then I installed `Vue CLI`.
After everything set right, I tried to create my `first-vue-app` but I was unable to create it.

I used the command:
`vue create first-vue-app`

then I got

```
priyanhomeoffice@HomeComputer:~/VSCodeProjects/LearnVue/Section7$ vue create first-vue-app
/home/priyanhomeoffice/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/ProjectPackageManager.js:129
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: You are using an outdated version of NPM.
It does not support some core functionalities of Vue CLI.
Please upgrade your NPM version.
    at new PackageManager (/home/priyanhomeoffice/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/ProjectPackageManager.js:129:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/priyanhomeoffice/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/util/getVersions.js:6:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/priyanhomeoffice/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.2/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/lib/Creator.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)

Node.js v18.18.2
priyanhomeoffice@HomeComputer:~/VSCodeProjects/LearnVue/Section7$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all directories and files.
Remove the last few lines containing nvm from .bashrc
Remove .npm directory.

I purged everything and reinstalled it. It works with

Node version: 18.18.2
npm Version: 9.8.1
Vue CLI: 5.0.8